# This code is for Breadth first Search will it work fine for every Binary tree?

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;
 struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

Node* newNode(int data){
    Node* new_node = (Node*)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->left = new_node->right = NULL;
    return new_node;
}
queue<Node*> q;
void print(Node *root){
    if(root == NULL)    
        return; 
    if(root->left !=NULL)
        q.push(root->left);
    if(root->right != NULL)
        q.push(root->right);
    printf("%d ", (q.front())->data);
    q.pop();
    print(q.front());
}

int main(){
    Node *root = newNode(1);
    root->left = newNode(2);
    root->right = newNode(3);
    root->left->left = newNode(4);
    root->left->right = newNode(5);
    root->right->left = newNode(6);
    root->right->right = newNode(7);
    root->left->left->left = newNode(8);
    root->left->left->right = newNode(9);
    root->left->right->left = newNode(10);
    root->left->right->right = newNode(11);
    root->right->left->left = newNode(12);
    root->right->left->right = newNode(13);
    root->right->right->left = newNode(14);
    root->right->right->right = newNode(15);

    q.push(root);
    print(root);

    return 0;
}
```

Extremely sorry for the main funcn mess
it prints the output as : 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15

will this stuff work properly or there is some problem  . I am currently learning dsa so any suggestion would help

Comment: The StackOverflow `dsa` tag does not mean Data Structures & Algorithms.

Comment: This is not C++. Everything here is written like C. You may get more people if it is ocrrectly tagged.

Comment: PS. `any test case that I am missing`. I don't see any tests.

Comment: `Node* new_node = (Node*)calloc(1,sizeof(Node));` -- Why are you using `calloc` in a C++ program?  Change that `Node` data to `std::string`, and everything falls apart, all due to using `calloc`.

Comment: Look up B-Tree, B*Tree and Red/Black tree.  There are binary trees that contain pages (arrays) of links to subtrees.  So, no, your BST algorithm will not work on all Binary Trees.

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you don't need to specify `struct` when creating pointers or instances of a struct.